# Matlab. Poisson fit. Factorial

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, factorial, poisson

I have a histogram that seems to fit a poisson distribution.
In order to fit it, I declare the function myself as follows

```
xdata; ydata; % Arrays in which I have stored the data. 
%Ydata tell us how many times the xdata is repeated in the set.

fun= @(x,xdata) (exp(-x(1))*(x(1).^(xdata)) )/(factorial(xdata)) %Function I 
% want to use in the fit. It is a poisson distribution.

x0=[1]; %Approximated value of the parameter lambda to help the fit

p=lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata); % Fit in the least square sense
```

I find an error. It probably has to do with the "factorial". Any ideas?

Comment: why is there a `.` in `factorial(.xdata))` ?

Comment: I am dealing with a vector. Maybe the "." is wrongly placed. But there should be one, right?

Comment: No. The `.*` is different from `*` . `*` is the dot product, `.*` is the element wise multiplication. But factorial just works on vectors and scalars the same.

Comment: I see. However, if I do not put any "." I find an error in "lsqcurvefit" step anyways. It says "Error using lsqcurvefit (line 248)
Function value and YDATA sizes are not equal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorial outputs a vector from vector xdata. Why are you using .xdata in factorial?

For example:

```
data = [1 2 3];
```

`factorial(data)` is then `[1! 2! 3!].`

Try `./factorial(xdata)` (I cannot recall if the dot is even necessary at this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *gamma(xdata+1)* function instead of *factorial(xdata)* function. Gamma function is a generalized form of factorial function which can be used for real and complex numbers. Thus, your code would be:

```
fun = @(x,xdata) exp(-x(1))*x(1).^xdata./gamma(xdata+1);
x = lsqcurvefit(fun,1,xdata,ydata);
```

Alternatively, you can MATLAB *fitdist* function which is already optimized and you might get better results:

```
pd = fitdist(xdata,'Poisson','Frequency',ydata);
pd.lambda
```